# Google ReCatpcha

Tags: php, javascript, html, html5

Tengo un problema en entender el Google ReCatpcha, he aqui mi código html

```
<form id="contact-form" class="contact-form" action="contact_form_handler.php" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
<p>
    <input id="name" class="required" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Nombre*" title="* Nombre">
</p>
<p>
    <input id="email" class="email required" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email*" title="* Email">
</p>
<p>
    <input id="number" name="number" type="text" placeholder="Teléfono">
</p>
<p>
    <textarea id="comment" class="required" name="message" placeholder="Consulta*" title="* Consulta"></textarea>
</p>
<div class="clearfix">
    <div style="width:20%;" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LfmbFQUAAAAABju6YU_SeON1f0kdbpVcluT1tGn"></div>
    <input type="submit" id="submit-button" name="submit" class="btn-small btn-orange pull-right" value="Enviar mensaje">
    <img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" id="ajax-loader" class="pull-right" alt="cargando...">
</div>
<div id="error-container"></div>
<div id="message-container">&nbsp;</div>
```

y aquí está mi código php, ya inserte el script y div necesario, la cuestión radica en el php por la condición

```html
<?php
/**
 * File Name: contact_form_handler.php
 *
 * Send message function to process contact form submission
 *
 */
if ( isset( $_POST['email'] ) ):

    $name = filter_var( $_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
    $from_email = filter_var( $_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL );
    $number = filter_var( $_POST['number'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
    $message = filter_var( $_POST['message'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );

    $to_email = "robot@inspirythemes.com";    // provide your target email address here
    $to_name = "John Doe";

    $email_subject = 'You Have Received a Message From ' . $name . '.';

    if ( ! empty( $subject ) ) {
        $email_subject = $subject . '.';
    }

    $email_body = "You have Received a message from: " . $name . " <br/>";

    if (!empty( $number )) {
        $email_body .= "Phone Number: " . $number . " <br/><br/>";
    }

    $email_body .= "Their additional message is as follows." . " <br/><br/>";

    $email_content = nl2br( $message ) . " <br/><br/>";

    $email_reply =  "You can contact " . $name . " via email, " . $from_email ;

    $prepared_message = $email_body . $email_content . $email_reply;

    // You can consult https://github.com/eoghanobrien/php-simple-mail for more details
    require 'class.simple_mail.php';

    /* @var SimpleMail $mail */
    $mail = new SimpleMail();
    $mail->setTo( $to_email, $to_name )
        ->setSubject( $email_subject )
        ->setFrom( $from_email, $name )
        ->addMailHeader( 'Reply-To', $from_email, $name )
        ->addGenericHeader( 'X-Mailer', 'PHP/' . phpversion() )
        ->addGenericHeader( 'Content-Type', 'text/html; charset="utf-8"' )
        ->setMessage( $prepared_message );
    $sent = $mail->send();

    //echo $mail->debug();

    if( $sent ) {
        echo json_encode(array(
            'success' => true,
            'message' => "Message Sent Successfully!"
        ));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array(
                'success' => false,
                'message' => "Server Error:  mail method failed!"
            )
        );
    }

else:

    echo json_encode(array(
            'success' => false,
            'message' => "Invalid Request !"
        )
    );

endif;

die;
```

Comment: ¿Cual es tu pregunta?

Comment: la cuestión radica en la condición, la cual no se si tiene que ir antes que el isset(post['email']) o dentro de él antes de enviar el email

Comment: La validación del _captcha_ se hace siempre **antes** de validar cualquier otro dato, ya que es obligatorio... Una vez tienes el ok del _captcha_, pasas a realizar el resto de validaciones y por último realizar el envío del mail.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, lo hice tal y como me dijiste y perdonar por hacer estas preguntas tan tontas pero a veces no veo tales minucias como estas

Answer (score 1):

```
 /*Archivo php donde comprobar el formulario*/

require 'recaptchalib.php';
$secret = "clave secreta";
$response = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
$remoteip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$recaptcha = new ReCaptcha($secret);
$resp = $recaptcha->verifyResponse($response, $remoteip);


if($resp){
  //comprobar el email,et...
}
else{
  //devolver el error esperado
 }
```